# how to check one-one and onto correspondence between two sets in Real

Tags: functions

Let $A=\{x∣0<x<1\}$ and $B=\{x∣1<x<2\}$.
Which of the following statements is true?

1. There is a one to one, onto function from A to B.
2. There is no one to one, onto function from A to B taking rationals to rationals.
3. There is no one to one function from A to B which is onto.
4. There is no onto function from A to B which is one to one.

Comment: If $f : A \to B$ is defined by $f(a) = a+1$, what can you conclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's answer 1.  In terms of their structure, the line segments from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 2 are for all intents and purposes identical.

One to one means that one can map every point of $A$ to exactly one and only one matching point on $B$.

Onto means every point in $B$ has a corresponding point in $A$.

So the function $x+1$ maps them perfectly satisfying both of these properties.